# problem in sprintf function

Tags: c, file

I am coding for a rar password cracker. I am reading the password from a file and passing it to sprintf function. This is the code.

```
FILE* fp = fopen("password.txt","r");
    while ( fgets ( pword, sizeof(pword), fp ) != NULL )
    {
          sprintf(command, "rar e -p%s realp.rar", pword);
          printf(command);
          //system(command);                                               
    }
```

This code looks fine but it's not working. Therefore I commented the system fubction and printing the variable "command". The output is like this :

```
rar e -pfirstpassword
     realp.rarrar e -psecondpassword
     realp.rarrar e -pthirdpassword
     realp.rarrar e -pfourthpassword realp.rar
```

I can see it's breaking.The output should come like this.

```
rar e -pfirstpassword realp.rar
rar e -psecondpassword realp.rar
rar e -pthirdpassword realp.rar
rar e -pfourthpassword realp.rar
```

can anybody help me to solve this? Thanks in advance.

- operating system : windows 7
- compiler : dev c++

Comment: *Not working* is not a very precise problem description.

Comment: I formatted the output. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question. What is not working when you use the `system` command? Are you getting an error message, does your program/computer crash, do apples start to fall from the sky, ... ?

Comment: What's the content of the file?

Comment: I think, I did not explain the problem properly. This code should extract the rar file but it's not extracting. Instead it's opening all the options of rar command.

Comment: The file contains different strings including the actual password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newline found by fgets() is kept in 'pword'. Remove it and then print each line with a \n instead and see if it works.

See the man page for [fgets()](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/).

Try adding the following line after the fgets() call.

```
pword[strlen(pword) - 1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I can't understand. Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Your pword each time through the while loop is followed by a new line.
Thus the output:

```
rar e -pfirstpassword [NEWLINE]
     realp.rar
```

You do not end command with a new line.
Thus the output:

```
[command1][command2][command3]
```

Combining the two problems (adding braces around each loop iteration you get:

```
{rar e -pfirstPassword [NEWLINE]
         realp.rar}{rar e -psecondPassword [NEWLINE]
         realp.rar}
```

To fix the problem. Remove the new lines from the end of each password line.

---

To expand: 
fgets documentation for windows is available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c37dh6kf(VS.80).aspx

From the documentation:

> The fgets function reads a string from
>   the input stream argument and stores
>   it in str. fgets reads characters from
>   the current stream position to and
>   including the first newline character,
>   to the end of the stream, or until the
>   number of characters read is equal to
>   n – 1, whichever comes first. The
>   result stored in str is appended with
>   a null character. The newline
>   character, if read, is included in the
>   string.

The Newline character is therefore included as part of the string written to pword. As you don't remove this character there is a newline in the middle of command when you write it with printf.

Comment: means I have to modify the file that contains password?
I can't do that because the code i have written to generate all possible combination of a word, prints all the strings in new line. I can change that but I don't think it will be a good idea. Can I change this code and solve the problem??

Comment: Yes, as shown in the answer above, all you have to do is remove the newline character from the string. The code fragment shown.  --   pword[strlen(pword) - 1] = '\0';   --
will do that in a simple way.